# Count how many rows with one column value have another column value greater than 0 postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Let's say I have a table like so

| Name | Value | Time | Transactions |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | 7 | 8am | {C_12321,tfcsaffa} |
| Mike | 2 | 7am | {gf34g34g} |
| John | 1 | 4am | {C_342342,dsf34gf43} |
| Ryan | 0 | 2am | {C_12321,4g34g54g} |

And I would like to query the table to output all the unique names (John, Mike, and Ryan) as well as the number of Value columns each one has that is greater than 0. (NOT the sum of their value columns).

The output should be like so:

John 2
Mike 1
Ryan 0

So far I have been able to output the unique names with

`SELECT "Name" FROM table GROUP BY "Name"`

However the rest escapes me.

Thank you!

Comment: I do not know exactly how to IF in pgsql, but in mysql I would do sum(if(value>0,1,0)), this method is used when you want to count and include the zeros, which is part of the problem here

Comment: `select name, sum((value > 0)::int) from able group by name;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use FILTER():

```
SELECT "Name" 
    , COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE "Value" > 0)
FROM table 
GROUP BY "Name"
ORDER BY 2 DESC; -- 2nd column
```

Advice: Don't use UPPER case in your table or column definitions. Such a pain in the *** to keep on using " and " forever...

Comment: postgresql is beautiful, thank you!

Comment: How could we take this one step further and count only the columns where value is greater than 0 as 1, but only if ANOTHER column's array does NOT contain a string match like "C_", I've edited the question above

Comment: @Ethan You can extend the WHERE condition in the filter, just like any other WHERE condition: `(WHERE "Value" > 0 AND other_colomn = 'foo')`. I would recommend to avoid the usage of arrays.

Comment: would you suggest I convert that column to a string instead? Eventually we'll have to iterate through the objects of the array as each one is a separate transaction with information attached to it... could I do `(WHERE "Value" > 0 AND other_colomn LIKE '%foo%')` if it remains an array? Or should I first do `ARRAY_TO_STRING()`... not sure best practice

Comment: @Ethan IMHO you should store multiple values in multiple records, in a different table and use a foreign key to relate these records to your current table. Using a single string to represent multi values would be imho the worst solution.